# Android passing JSON data using POST method to server

Tags: android, json, android-parser

I have following JSON string with base64 image content. Will you help me how can I post this JSON as Multipart:

```
{
    "TakeoffID": "2",
    "address": ",nexhex",
    "city": "Xrk Zed",
    "state": "AZ",
    "date": "12/08/2015",
    "ViewNote": "",
    "ViewPhoto1": "base64ImageContent",
    "ViewPhoto2": "base64ImageContent",
    "ViewPhoto3": "base64ImageContent",
    "TakeoffDoneBy": "Jxehx",
    "AcctName": "Gsgve",
    "LoginUserID": "46669",
    "jobId": "whshs",
    "LineItems": [
        {
            "OrderLineid": "544",
            "OrderLineTypeid": "Post Light",
            "OrderLineQty": "2",
            "OrderLinePhoto1": "base64ImageContent",
            "OrderLinePhoto2": "base64ImageContent",
            "OrderLinePhoto3": "base64ImageContent",
            "OrderLineNotes": "",
            "OrderLineLocation": "Post Lights"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Since it is a Base64 encoded image, shouldn't you just send a normal `application/json` request? Go over [OkHttp Recipes](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes). It has all what you need.

Comment: Indeed. It makes no sense to send json as multi part.

Comment: @Ravi, Have you tried with below answer and Is it working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way to do this is, first convert your request json into simple map like

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
```

For "LineItems" : "LineItems" as key and it values json as string format and add into this map.

Then use below method to call the Webservice.

```
private JSONObject sendRequest(String urlString, Map<String, String> map, String fileKey,  File file) {
        StringBuilder strData= null;
        JSONObject resObj = null;
        try {
            Log.i("Send request", urlString+"="+map);
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(50000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(50000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            if(map == null)
            {
                map = new HashMap<>();
            }
            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            for (HashMap.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                String k = entry.getKey();
                String v = entry.getValue();
                reqEntity.addPart(k, new StringBody(v));
            }

            if(file != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(fileKey))
            {
                FileBody filebody = new FileBody(file, "image/*");
                reqEntity.addPart(fileKey, filebody);
            }

            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.addRequestProperty("Content-length", reqEntity.getContentLength() + "");
            conn.addRequestProperty(reqEntity.getContentType().getName(), reqEntity.getContentType().getValue());
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            reqEntity.writeTo(os);
            os.close();
            conn.connect();
            if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                String sResponse;
                strData = new StringBuilder();
                while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    strData = strData.append(sResponse);
                }
            }
            if(strData != null)
                resObj = new JSONObject(strData.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return resObj;
    }
```

Comment: Will you explain me, how above method will work for my JSON string as i shared JSONString

Comment: You can convert your above json into Map like:
map.put("TakeoffID", "2"); and so on.. call the above method using this map reference.

Comment: map.put("LineItems", "[
        {
            "OrderLineid": "544",
            "OrderLineTypeid": "Post Light",
            "OrderLineQty": "2",
            "OrderLinePhoto1": "base64ImageContent",
            "OrderLinePhoto2": "base64ImageContent",
            "OrderLinePhoto3": "base64ImageContent",
            "OrderLineNotes": "",
            "OrderLineLocation": "Post Lights"
        }
    ]");